# I git pulled without saving changes made on local repo

Tags: git, pull, undo

I made changes on local repo, but forgot to commit the changes. I ran git pull and now I've lost the code I added on local repo. How do I reverse changes made on local repo after running git pull, or reverse a git pull to go back to the unstagged changes.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` means:

1. run `git fetch`; then (assuming step 1 succeeds)
2. run a second Git command.

That *second* Git command is the one that caused problems.  Exactly what problems, we can't tell you until you tell us which second Git command you chose to have `git pull` run.

(If the second command was `git rebase` *and* you set up rebase to use autostash *and* the rebase failed—none of which you showed in your question: see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)—then I know what happened, but if not, it's not clear.  Meanwhile StackOverflow is being balky, despite StackStatus saying everything is fine.)